# Testing routes with digest authentication

Tags: node.js, request, passport.js, digest-authentication, supertest

I'm trying to write some tests against an API which is protected by a digest strategy.

```
request.post(url + '/route', {
  auth: {
    'user': 'anakin@empire.gx',
    'pass': 'l1ghts4ber',
    'sendImmediately': false
  },
  json: true,
  body: { some: 'thing' }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(error, body);
});
```

I tried supertest and request but both fail the authentication. The API uses the passport-http digest method. Any ideas?

**Update**

I had some problems first with curl and figured my passwords were generated with bcrypt, so I changed them in the database to plain text passwords. I tried to get it to work with SHA1 but that didn't work out right away, for the sake of testing the request I'll leave it plain for now.

This is the output from curl, the request in the tests still doesn't work.

```
curl -X POST --digest -u "anakin@empire.gx:l1ghts4ber" http://localhost:3005/api/route -v
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fa48380b600
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fa48380b600) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 3005 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3005 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'anakin@empire.gx'
> POST /api/route HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:3005
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Powered-By: Express
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< access-control-allow-headers: content-type, accept, x-requested-with, authorization
< access-control-expose-headers: WWW-Authenticate
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Administrators@myapp.com", nonce="6aD1vEM44Pi5cfWBi469tug1vQciQS0u", qop="auth"
< Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2013 10:19:24 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost:3005/api/route'
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x7fa482d0c460
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3005 (#0)
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fa48380b600
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fa48380b600) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Server auth using Digest with user 'anakin@empire.gx'
> POST /api/route HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Digest username="anakin@empire.gx", realm="Administrators@myapp.com", nonce="6aD1vEM44Pi5cfWBi469tug1vQciQS0u", uri="/api/route", cnonce="ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDEzODA5MjA4ODY=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="2c7aaaa198414749a47684d2d8aefea1"
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:3005
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< access-control-allow-headers: content-type, accept, x-requested-with, authorization
< access-control-expose-headers: WWW-Authenticate
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 2
< Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2013 10:19:24 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
```

*Update 2*
After modifying request a little bit, I finally have the exact same headers as with curl, but still get a 401 on the response.

```
curl:
{ 'user-agent': 'curl/7.30.0',
  host: '127.0.0.1:3005',
  accept: '*/*' }
POST /api/route 401 1ms
{ authorization: 'Digest username="anakin@empire.gx", realm="Administrators@myapp.com", nonce="fpf9MByyMQItfEob3u9QD4v86K3byCBZ", uri="/api/route", cnonce="ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDEzODA4Mjk4NzQ=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="c766607c032fa142cd9f932977931a3a"',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.30.0',
  host: '127.0.0.1:3005',
  accept: '*/*' }
POST /api/route 200 1ms - 2b

request:
{ host: '127.0.0.1:3005',
  accept: 'application/json',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '75',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
POST /api/route 401 1ms
{ accept: 'application/json',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '75',
  authorization: 'Digest username="anakin@empire.gx", realm="Administrators@myapp.com", nonce="mdOAymaut4VyndpvyJYuKmXLlnTNcvZD", uri="/api/route", qop=auth, response="d064b7a5140b979ec7dc7b027a6cb070", nc=00000001, cnonce="NT1UOADbjjIaxfI8kPeLHZk5FJIRs3uOzejTUZhlxh86Blmua7YKctF0NUPHUn"',
  host: '127.0.0.1:3005',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
POST /api/route 401 75ms
```

Comment: Try with cURL on the command line and use that as your reference known-good client code. That will let you be certain your credentials are correct. I don't see anything wrong with the above snippet at a glance. We'd need to some the request/response details to debug intelligently.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLyons, I added some more information. I'm a bit puzzled and frustrated with digest auth, it seems really complicated. Wonder if I changing to oauth would be simpler.

Comment: OK, next I'd add code in express to log all the request headers and see if what request.js is sending matches what curl is sending. You can use a middleware at the very top of the stack for this.

Comment: Done. There were some issues with qop and nc in request, but even after modifying that, it doesn't work. I checked the algorithms in request and it's the same as I use it in a different (working) digest mechanism.

var ha1 = md5(self._user + ':' + challenge.realm + ':' + self._pass)
var ha2 = md5(self.method + ':' + self.uri.path)
var digestResponse = md5(ha1 + ':' + challenge.nonce + ':1::auth:' + ha2)

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think you can make the supertest examples work by attempting to send the right encrypted bits. The trouble is that the server responds with a nonce and that has to be used to construct the right reply